# Why is an XImage's data pointer null when capturing using XShmGetImage?

Tags: c++, x11, shared-memory, xlib

I'm writing a program to rapidly capture images from one window, modify them, and output them to another window using Xlib with C++.  I have this working via XGetImage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

const int TEST_SIZE = 512;

int main()
{
  // Open default display
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
  int screen = DefaultScreen(display);
  Window rootWin = RootWindow(display, screen);
  GC graphicsContext = DefaultGC(display, screen);

  // Create new window and subscribe to events
  long blackPixel = BlackPixel(display, screen);
  long whitePixel = WhitePixel(display, screen);
  Window newWin = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, rootWin, 0, 0, TEST_SIZE, TEST_SIZE, 1, blackPixel, whitePixel);
  XMapWindow(display, newWin);
  XSelectInput(display, newWin, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);

  // Main event loop for new window
  XImage *image;
  XEvent event;
  bool exposed = false;
  bool killWindow = false;
  while (!killWindow)
  {
    // Handle pending events
    if (XPending(display) > 0)
    {
      XNextEvent(display, &event);
      if (event.type == Expose)
      {
        exposed = true;
      } else if (event.type == NoExpose)
      {
        exposed = false;
      } else if (event.type == KeyPress)
      {
        killWindow = true;
      }
    }

    // Capture the original image
    image = XGetImage(display, rootWin, 0, 0, TEST_SIZE, TEST_SIZE, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);

    // Modify the image
    if (image->data != nullptr)
    {
      long pixel = 0;
      for (int x = 0; x < image->width; x++)
      {
        for (int y = 0; y < image->height; y++)
        {
          // Invert the color of each pixel
          pixel = XGetPixel(image, x, y);
          XPutPixel(image, x, y, ~pixel);
        }
      }
    }

    // Output the modified image
    if (exposed && killWindow == false)
    {
      XPutImage(display, newWin, graphicsContext, image, 0, 0, 0, 0, TEST_SIZE, TEST_SIZE);
    }
    XDestroyImage(image);
  }

  // Goodbye
  XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

It generates output like this:  https://streamable.com/hovg9

I'm happy to have gotten this far, but from what I've read the performance isn't going to scale very well because it has to allocate space for a new image at every frame. In fact, without the call to XDestroyImage at the end of the loop this program fills up all 16GB of memory on my machine in a matter of seconds!

It seems the recommended approach here is to to set up a shared memory space where X can write the contents of each frame and my program can subsequently read and modify them without the need for any extra allocation.  Since the call to XShmGetImage blocks and waits for IPC I believe this means I won't have to worry about any concurrency issues in the shared space.

I've attempted to implement the XShmGetImage approach with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XShm.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

const int TEST_SIZE = 512;

int main()
{
  // Open default display
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
  int screen = DefaultScreen(display);
  Window rootWin = RootWindow(display, screen);
  GC graphicsContext = DefaultGC(display, screen);

  // Create new window and subscribe to events
  long blackPixel = BlackPixel(display, screen);
  long whitePixel = WhitePixel(display, screen);
  Window newWin = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, rootWin, 0, 0, TEST_SIZE, TEST_SIZE, 1, blackPixel, whitePixel);
  XMapWindow(display, newWin);
  XSelectInput(display, newWin, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);

  // Allocate shared memory for image capturing
  Visual *visual = DefaultVisual(display, 0);
  XShmSegmentInfo shminfo;
  int depth = DefaultDepth(display, screen);
  XImage *image = XShmCreateImage(display, visual, depth, ZPixmap, nullptr, &shminfo, TEST_SIZE, TEST_SIZE);
  shminfo.shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, image->bytes_per_line * image->height, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
  shmat(shminfo.shmid, nullptr, 0);
  shminfo.shmaddr = image->data;
  shminfo.readOnly = False;
  XShmAttach(display, &shminfo);

  // Main event loop for new window
  XEvent event;
  bool exposed = false;
  bool killWindow = false;
  while (!killWindow)
  {
    // Handle pending events
    if (XPending(display) > 0)
    {
      XNextEvent(display, &event);
      if (event.type == Expose)
      {
        exposed = true;
      } else if (event.type == NoExpose)
      {
        exposed = false;
      } else if (event.type == KeyPress)
      {
        killWindow = true;
      }
    }

    // Capture the original image
    XShmGetImage(display, rootWin, image, 0, 0, AllPlanes);

    // Modify the image
    if (image->data != nullptr) // NEVER TRUE.  DATA IS ALWAYS NULL!
    {
      long pixel = 0;
      for (int x = 0; x < image->width; x++)
      {
        for (int y = 0; y < image->height; y++)
        {
          // Invert the color of each pixel
          pixel = XGetPixel(image, x, y);
          XPutPixel(image, x, y, ~pixel);
        }
      }
    }

    // Output the modified image
    if (exposed && killWindow == false)
    {
      XShmPutImage(display, newWin, graphicsContext, image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512, false);
    }
  }

  // Goodbye
  XFree(image);
  XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

Somehow, the images are still being captured and sent to the new window, but the data pointer within the XImage is always null.  I can't modify any of the contents and any usage of the XGetPixel and XPutPixel macros will fail.  Notice in this video that none of the colors are being inverted like before:  https://streamable.com/dckyv

This doesn't make any sense to me.  Clearly the data is still being transferred between the windows, but where is it in the XImage structure?  How can I access it via code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't reading the signature for shmat correctly.  It doesn't have a void return type, it returns a void pointer.  This needs to be assigned directly to the XImage's data pointer in order for the data pointer to do anything.

In the call to XShmPutImage the shared memory location is referenced internally rather than the XImage's data pointer which is why this was still working even without utilizing the return value from shmat.

Here's the working code, along with a few other additions which I made for error handling and teardown:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XShm.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

const int TEST_SIZE = 512;

static int handleXError(Display *display, XErrorEvent *event)
{
  printf("XErrorEvent triggered!\n");
  printf("error_code: %d", event->error_code);
  printf("minor_code: %d", event->minor_code);
  printf("request_code: %d", event->request_code);
  printf("resourceid: %lu", event->resourceid);
  printf("serial: %d", event->error_code);
  printf("type: %d", event->type);
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  // Open default display
  XSetErrorHandler(handleXError);
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
  int screen = DefaultScreen(display);
  Window rootWin = RootWindow(display, screen);
  GC graphicsContext = DefaultGC(display, screen);

  // Create new window and subscribe to events
  long blackPixel = BlackPixel(display, screen);
  long whitePixel = WhitePixel(display, screen);
  Window newWin = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, rootWin, 0, 0, TEST_SIZE, TEST_SIZE, 1, blackPixel, whitePixel);
  XMapWindow(display, newWin);
  XSelectInput(display, newWin, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);

  // Allocate shared memory for image capturing
  XShmSegmentInfo shminfo;
  Visual *visual = DefaultVisual(display, screen);
  int depth = DefaultDepth(display, screen);
  XImage *image = XShmCreateImage(display, visual, depth, ZPixmap, nullptr, &shminfo, TEST_SIZE, TEST_SIZE);
  shminfo.shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, image->bytes_per_line * image->height, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
  image->data = (char*)shmat(shminfo.shmid, 0, 0);
  shminfo.shmaddr = image->data;
  shminfo.readOnly = False;
  XShmAttach(display, &shminfo);
  XSync(display, false);
  shmctl(shminfo.shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);

  // Main event loop for new window
  XEvent event;
  bool exposed = false;
  bool killWindow = false;
  while (!killWindow)
  {
    // Handle pending events
    if (XPending(display) > 0)
    {
      XNextEvent(display, &event);
      if (event.type == Expose)
      {
        exposed = true;
      } else if (event.type == NoExpose)
      {
        exposed = false;
      } else if (event.type == KeyPress)
      {
        killWindow = true;
      }
    }

    // Capture the original image
    XShmGetImage(display, rootWin, image, 0, 0, AllPlanes);

    // Modify the image
    if(image->data != nullptr) // NEVER TRUE.  DATA IS ALWAYS NULL!
    {
      long pixel = 0;
      for (int x = 0; x < image->width; x++)
      {
        for (int y = 0; y < image->height; y++)
        {
          // Invert the color of each pixel
          pixel = XGetPixel(image, x, y);
          XPutPixel(image, x, y, ~pixel);
        }
      }
    }

    // Output the modified image
    if (exposed && killWindow == false)
    {
      XShmPutImage(display, newWin, graphicsContext, image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512, false);
    }
  }

  // Goodbye
  XShmDetach(display, &shminfo);
  XDestroyImage(image);
  shmdt(shminfo.shmaddr);
  XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```